# Get login information from instagram application

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am following the [official documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) on getting instagram access token.
Since it is more secure I implemented Server-side (Explicit) Flow.

It works fine on browser, but on mobile devices it runs https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize inside a webview, which is the expected behaviour. But **mobile device users probably have instagram application installed and it would be better if I could get the authorization from that application.**

I am using [cordova-facebook-plugin4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) for the same need on facebook authentication flow. But couldnt find a plugin like that on instagram.

I tried [ng-cordova-oauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth), but it run the same and tried to get login info from webview.

Project client side is build with angular.js and packed with cordova for ios and android native, And I have api running on .Net